# Validating Unique Fields in Django

Tags: django, unique, save

I don't know if I'm approaching the problem in the right way. The intended outcome is to have a form that displays only `name` and `description`. Once the user submits the form I want to add the current user as `owner` and check if there's already an entry that has the same `name` and `user`. If there is, I want to return the form with errors. If not, I want to save `Status`.

My model:

```
class Status(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name','owner')
```

My View:

```
def settings_status(request):
    status_form = StatusForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        status_form = StatusForm(request.POST)
            if status_form.is_valid():
                new_status = Status()
                new_status.name = status_form.cleaned_data['name']
                new_status.description = status_form.cleaned_data['description']
                new_status.owner = request.user
                new_status.save()

    return render_to_response('base/settings_status.html',{
        'status_form'           :       status_form,
}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I have tried numerous things, but I keep running into the problem that if I add `owner` to the object separately then it isn't available to the model's `clean` function and therefore can't be used to check if `name` and `owner` are unique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several ways to do this:

for example, passing in the user (owner) to the form:

forms.py:

```
class StatusForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user','')
        super(StatusForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'] = forms.CharField(label='Name')
        self.fields['description'] = CharField(label='Description', widget=forms.Textarea)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        name = cleaned_data.get('name')

        if Status.objects.filter(name=name, owner=self.user).exists():
            self._errors['name'] self.error_class(['Status with this name exists'])  

        return cleaned_data
```

views.py:

```
def settings_status(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        status_form = StatusForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
            if status_form.is_valid():
                new_status = Status()
                new_status.name = status_form.cleaned_data['name']
                new_status.description = status_form.cleaned_data['description']
                new_status.owner = request.user
                new_status.save()
    else:
        status_form = StatusForm(user=request.user)

    context = {'status_form':status_form,}

    return render_to_response('base/settings_status.html', context,
                context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Also look at setting initial data depending on your form setup and consider using a ModelForm.